# A tr element in a table is discarding the top CSS property applied to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, fixed-header-tables

I am working on a project in which i have code structure as -

```
<div id="scroll" class="datagrid" style="position: relative">
<table id="datatable" class="datatable">
<thead id="header" class="header">
<tr>
....
</tr>
<tbody id="content">
<tr>
....
</tr>
</tbody>
```

For the tr in thead, we had an expression as -

```
.header tr
{
  top: expression(document.getElementById('datagrid').scrollTop);
}
```

In IE8, this expression was evaluated and the top was set so that header was always visible.
However since expressions dont work in IE11, hence we can write a JavaScript function for the purpose.

However in IE11,top property doesnt work as expected. Even after it is applied, the header is not visible.

Can someone please suggest what might possibly be going wrong?

PS: The Javascript i tried was :

```
document.getElementById("header").getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].style.top = document.getElementById('scroll').scrollTop ;
```

Comment: Can you post the javascript you tried?

Comment: I added the following javascript to the onscroll event : onscroll="document.getElementById("header").getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].style.top = document.getElementById('scroll').scrollTop ;"

Comment: @HarshRawat That way it will only be applied to the first TR. To apply the top style to all TRs you must use a for loop like in my solution.

Comment: @chris97ong Yes Chris i wanted to apply it to first row only as it only contained the relevant headers.

Comment: Are you running that function every time the user scrolls, or only once? You may need to post more of your code for us to see what's going on, including your css.

Answer (score 0):

CSS expressions only work in IE8 and below.

You can use a Javascript function to replace the expression like this:

```
var headerTR = document.getElementById("header").getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var i = 0; i < headerTR.length; i++) {
    headerTR[i].style.top = document.getElementById('datagrid').scrollTop;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: He said that in his question. He is saying the JS doesn't work and asking why.

Comment: Yes as Bodacious pointed out, i have tried javascript. However the top property is not applied.

Comment: @HarshRawat Hmm, that's strange. I just modified my code, maybe try it out to see if it works? There's no reason for it not to work

Comment: @chris97ong Exactly however it is not working in my case. I read somewhere that if the position is set as relative then the top CSS property is discarded. Is that so?

Comment: @HarshRawat Not too sure, I think you should google it up, my CSS is not the best :P         Does `position: absolute` work?

Comment: @chris97ong No It distorts the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

`style.top` takes a string value. Try adding `+"px"` to your expression.

```
document.getElementById("header").getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].style.top = document.getElementById('scroll').scrollTop+"px";
```

Also, make sure you are running the expression every time a scroll occurs. You could use `onscroll="someFunction()"`, for example.

```
<div id="scroll" class="datagrid" style="position: relative" onscroll="scrollFunction(this.id)">
...
<script>
    function scrollFunction(scrollId) {
        var theHeader = document.getElementById('header').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
        var scrollBoxTop = document.getElementById(scrollId).scrollTop;

        theHeader.style.top = scrollBoxTop + "px";
    }
</script>
```